# How do i get variable type Double to recognize a 0 at the end of a decimal

Tags: java, double

I am trying to make a program to find sig-figs, and i need to know the length of a Double data type.  My issue is that when i have a variable such as 1.440, the Double excludes the end zero, which throws off the length.  I would use a decimal format but my code will (when fully operational) randomly generate the length of the variables along with the values themselves, so the format would change.  Is there a way I can make the Double data type keep the 0 at the end?  Thanks!

Comment: Not with double but you can create a wrapper class that holds `double` and number of digits after `0` and process it accordingly

Comment: why not just add the zero to the end of every number or test for it and then add it.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `BigDecimal`...

Comment: If you need to preserve an end zero, it sounds like you'll need a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class, such as:

```
public class FixedLengthDouble {

    private double value;
    private int length;

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getFixedLengthValueAsString() {
        String toReturn = value + "";
        while (toReturn.length() < length) {
            toReturn += "0";
        }
    }

    public FixedLengthDouble(double value, int length) {
        this.value = value;
        this.length = length;
    }

}
```

You can create such an object by passing the value and its length as a string, so later you can get the fixed length value as a String.